# Showing absolutely convergence

Tags: analysis

Im having trouble with showing that this series: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k}\cdot{sin(3^{-k}x)} $$ is absolutely convergent in R.

I got this inequality but this doesnt help:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty |2^{k}\cdot{sin(3^{-k}x)}| \le\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k} $$ 
since $$2^{k}$$ diverges.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\sin(y)|\leq |y|$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty |2^{k}\cdot{\sin(3^{-k}x)}|\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty |2^{k}|\cdot |3^{-k}x| =|x|\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k =\frac{1}{1-\frac23}|x|=3|x|.$$